# Why are bitwise operators used for setting RegexOptions?

Tags: c#, regex

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yd1hzczs.aspx

> **Specifying the options**

> The options parameter is a bitwise OR combination of RegexOptions enumerated values.

> ```
> RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace;
> ```

What does this mean? Why is a bitwise operator used and what is the benefit instead of using an array, for example?

Comment: You mean why did they choose to have options specified with a bitwise operator? It's a fairly common way of passing flags to a function, and saves the overhead of passing in an array to a function as the underlying types would be unsigned int/char. Say RegexOptions.IgnoreCase is 1 and RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace is 2, then the options argument is 1 | 2 = 3. Then you can do `options & RegexOptions.IgnoreCase` to see whether the user wanted that option. It's just faster than arrays.

Comment: They are flags. [Read](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8447/enum-flags-attribute)

Comment: It is lightweight (implemented with a single integer, rather than an array of boolean). Think of an integer as an array of bit and you will see that you have an array 32 or 64 bools.

Answer (score 2):

This is actually enum flags. Each enum entry is associated with a number and using the bitwise operators you are actually operating on the numbers behind each enum name.

See this for more information: [What does the [Flags] Enum Attribute mean in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8447/enum-flags-attribute)

Comment: I would also look at the [MSDN Article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kxszd0kx(v=vs.80).aspx) on the `|` operator because it illustrates it's use as both a logical `OR` operator and a bitwise operator.